# lodash: create array on basis of object's child array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am learning [Lodash](http://lodash.com/) which is a javascript library.

Here, I am having an object like:

**Scenario #1:**

```
{
    name: 'abc'
    email: 'abc@example.com'
    z: [
        {
            time: '<any-time>',
            t: 't1'
        },
        {
            time: '<any-time>',
            t: 't2'
        },
        {
            time: '<any-time>',
            t: 't3'
        }
    ]
}
```

I want this result using lodash:

```
[
    {
        name: 'abc'
        email: 'abc@example.com'
        z: [
            {
                time: '<any-time>',
                t: 't1'
            }           
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'abc'
        email: 'abc@example.com'
        z: [
            {
                time: '<any-time>',
                t: 't2'
            }           
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'abc'
        email: 'abc@example.com'
        z: [
            {
                time: '<any-time>',
                t: 't3'
            }           
        ]
    }
]
```

**Scenario #2:**

```
{
    name: 'abc'
    email: 'abc@example.com'
    z: [
        {
            time: '<any-time>',
            t: 't1'
        },
        {
            time: '<any-time>',
            t: 't1'    // see here t1 repeated
        },
        {
            time: '<any-time>',
            t: 't3'
        }
    ]
}
```

then result should be:

```
[
    {
        name: 'abc'
        email: 'abc@example.com'
        z: [
            {
                time: '<any-time>',
                t: 't1'
            },
            {
                time: '<any-time>',
                t: 't1'
            }           
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'abc'
        email: 'abc@example.com'
        z: [
            {
                time: '<any-time>',
                t: 't3'
            }           
        ]
    }
]
```

Let me know if my details are not cleared to you.

Thanks :)

**EDIT:**
I tried following code,

```
var finalArr = [];
var baseInfo = _.omit(obj, 'z');
var childArr = obj.z;
for(var j = 0; j < childArr.length; j++){
    var flattenObj = angular.copy(baseInfo);
    flattenObj.z = [];
    flattenObj.z.push(childArr[j]);
    finalArr.push(flattenObj);
}
```

It simply handles scenario #1. And I think it uses more javascript than lodash.

Comment: @user2415266 check my edit

Answer (score 0):

This code works for both scenarios :

```
// I assume obj is the input object
var result = _.map(obj.z, function(value) {
    return {
        z : value,
        name : obj.name,
        email : obj.email
    };
});
```

Note that you don't need lodash at all for this example. You can simply write this :

```
// I assume obj is the input object
var result = obj.z.map(function(value) {
    return {
        z : value,
        name : obj.name,
        email : obj.email
    };
});
```

Comment: working well for scenario #1 but not in #2. If `t` has same values it should go in same `z` array.

Answer (score 0):

In a lodash chain, group the internal array by `t`, and then map each group to a new object:

```js
function collectAndCombine(obj) {
  return _(obj.z)
  .groupBy('t')
  .map(function(arr) {
    return _.assign(_.pick(obj, ['name', 'email']), { z: arr });
  })
  .value(); 
}

var obj1 = {
    name: 'abc',
    email: 'abc@example.com',
    z: [
        {
            time: '<any-time>',
            t: 't1'
        },
        {
            time: '<any-time>',
            t: 't2'
        },
        {
            time: '<any-time>',
            t: 't3'
        }
    ]
};

var obj2 = {
    name: 'abc',
    email: 'abc@example.com',
    z: [
        {
            time: '<any-time>',
            t: 't1'
        },
        {
            time: '<any-time>',
            t: 't1'    // see here t1 repeated
        },
        {
            time: '<any-time>',
            t: 't3'
        }
    ]
};

console.log(collectAndCombine(obj1));
  
console.log(collectAndCombine(obj2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it. It looks amazing :)

Comment: You're welcome :) I wasn't sure it's still relevant.